# Error in running an Android Studio program

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following error  and unable to run the program in the virtual device :

```
Session 'app':Installation did not succeed The application could not be installed: SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE
```

Comment: Have you considered googling or searching for the error message on Stack Overflow before asking a new question? There seem to be [plenty of others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE+%5Bandroid%5D) facing the same issue. If you've already tried the solutions proposed to others, please make sure you mention it in the question.

Comment: I have tried the proposed solutions (there are just two of them) and they do not work.